# When to Use Implicit and Explicit Wait while Switching Contexts and Finding Elements

Tags: java, appium, wait, android-context, android-uiautomator

I've been attempting add always use implicit and explicit waits while setting up basic universal functions for my mobile automation framework and avoiding Thread.sleep(time) method to keep better design practices. Lately I have been having issues of using waits just when using context switches. The errors I get are either TimeoutException, StaleElement References, or NoSuchElement Exceptions after switching contexts, even I know upon inspection, the element I seek is in view.

I'm not exactly looking for suggestions to resolve this, but I would like to know if this is a good approach with using waits with scenarios explained below.

(Edit) Scenario 1 (Resolved)
I've made a function to simulate if the user wants to resume an active app by calling the list of running apps then based on the AccessibilityId provided when calling the method, it will find the element based on that ID and select it to resume back to the app. (The code for Scenario 1 is listed below).

Scenario 2: 
I've made  a function that will continue to swipe in any direction, either up or down, until the target element the user entered into the method is found. Since swipes can only operate in Native Context, I switch set context to native to swipe, then switch back to the webview, or whatever the default view is to search for the target element. I'm also using UIautomator2 as my Automation, so not sure if I have to wait longer after switching back to webview context (Scenario 2 code listed below).

So far the only solutions I've attempted without resorting to Thread.sleep(time), has been adding explicit waits before either selecting the app(Scenario 1) or search if the element will when calling a findBy() (Scenario 2).

The cases I get with Scenario 1 is that it seems to find the element, since it performs the click() method, but it keeps looking for the element and can't find it, since that id no longer exists after resume to the app. I end up getting Timeout Exception or some cases stale element Exceptions. I'm not sure if using a different method inside wait.until() would resolve the issue with searching for element until it's found, then click.

(Edit) Scenario 1 code: (Resolved)

```
void viewActiveAppList() {

     driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.APP_SWITCH));
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}



void resumeApp(String appName){

    viewActiveAppList();
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
    MobileElement app = (MobileElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.AccessibilityId(appName)));
    app.click();
    driver.context(defaultContext);
    wait.waitUntilPageLoaded();

}
```

Scenario 2 Code:

swipeVertical:

```
void swipeVertical(double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, int duration) {
    driver.context(nativeContext);
    size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int width = (int) (size.width/2);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.getHeight() * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.getHeight() * finalPercentage);
    new AndroidTouchAction(driver)
        .press(PointOption.point(width, startPoint))
        .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(duration)))
        .moveTo(PointOption.point(width, endPoint))
        .release()
        .perform();
    driver.context(defaultContext);

}
```

swipeUntilFound:

```
void swipeUntilFound(By method, int attempts, MobileElement targetElement, Direction dir) {
    int limitCount = 0;
    double startScrollPoint = 0;
    double endScrollPoint = 0;
    switch (dir) {
        case up:
            startScrollPoint = 0.35;
            endScrollPoint = 0.8;
            break;
        case down:
            startScrollPoint = 0.8;
            endScrollPoint = 0.35;
            break;
    default:
        System.out.println("This method only supports directions up and down");
        break;
    }
    List<MobileElement> searchAfterSwipe = driver.findElements(method);
    while (searchAfterSwipe.isEmpty() || limitCount < attempts ) {
        swipeVertical(startScrollPoint, endScrollPoint, 3000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        searchAfterSwipe = driver.findElements(method);
        limitCount++;
    }
    if(limitCount == attempts) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find Specified Element.");
    }else {
        targetElement = driver.findElement(method);
        System.out.println("Element " + method.toString() + " was found.");
    }
}
```

(Edit)For Scenario one, I was getting TimeoutExceptions and Stale Element References. I was able to resolved this with switching to ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable() since I only need to find this the element until it becomes clickable.

For Scenario 2 here are the logs from my Remote server when capturing logs, I've trimmed it down to the portion where I'm getting issues with not finding the element with whatever By method I provide.

```
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/elements [39m[32m200[39m [90m385 ms - 108[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/context[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"name":"NATIVE_APP"}[39m
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Calling AppiumDriver.setContext() with args: ["NATIVE_APP","8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","CHROMIUM"]
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Responding to client with driver.setContext() result: null
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/context [39m[32m200[39m [90m79 ms - 14[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mGET[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/window/rect[39m
[HTTP] [90m{}[39m
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowRect() with args: ["8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/a0f6efb1-b817-427c-8b44-c79af74b08fe/window/current/size] with body: {}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"a0f6efb1-b817-427c-8b44-c79af74b08fe\",\"status\":0,\"value\":{\"height\":2560,\"width\":1440}}"
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Responding to client with driver.getWindowRect() result: {"width":1440,"height":2560,"x":0,"y":0}
[HTTP] [37m<-- GET /wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/window/rect [39m[32m200[39m [90m121 ms - 50[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/touch/perform[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"x":720,"y":896}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":3000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":720,"y":2048}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}[39m
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"press","options":{"x":720,"y":896}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":3000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":720,"y":2048}},{"action":"release","options":{}}],"8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/touch/perform' to command name 'performTouch'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /touch/perform] to [POST http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/a0f6efb1-b817-427c-8b44-c79af74b08fe/touch/perform] with body: {"startX":720,"startY":896,"endX":720,"endY":2048,"steps":84}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd","status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"0.6576757443982535-1"}]}
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId 67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd with 2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/elements [39m[32m200[39m [90m5157 ms - 108[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/context[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"name":"NATIVE_APP"}[39m
[W3C (2464c639)] Calling AppiumDriver.setContext() with args: ["NATIVE_APP","2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","CHROMIUM"]
[W3C (2464c639)] Responding to client with driver.setContext() result: null
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/context [39m[32m200[39m [90m90 ms - 14[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mGET[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/window/rect[39m
[HTTP] [90m{}[39m
[W3C (2464c639)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowRect() with args: ["2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://localhost:8201/wd/hub/session/16c2134a-84d5-4ca7-98d8-9cf96217376d/window/current/size] with body: {}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"16c2134a-84d5-4ca7-98d8-9cf96217376d\",\"status\":0,\"value\":{\"height\":1794,\"width\":1080}}"
[W3C (2464c639)] Responding to client with driver.getWindowRect() result: {"width":1080,"height":1794,"x":0,"y":0}
[HTTP] [37m<-- GET /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/window/rect [39m[32m200[39m [90m283 ms - 50[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/touch/perform[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"x":540,"y":627}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":3000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":540,"y":1435}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}[39m
[W3C (2464c639)] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"press","options":{"x":540,"y":627}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":3000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":540,"y":1435}},{"action":"release","options":{}}],"2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/touch/perform' to command name 'performTouch'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /touch/perform] to [POST http://localhost:8201/wd/hub/session/16c2134a-84d5-4ca7-98d8-9cf96217376d/touch/perform] with body: {"startX":540,"startY":627,"endX":540,"endY":1435,"steps":84}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"a0f6efb1-b817-427c-8b44-c79af74b08fe","status":0,"value":true}
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Responding to client with driver.performTouch() result: true
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/touch/perform [39m[32m200[39m [90m11402 ms - 14[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347/context[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"name":"CHROMIUM"}[39m
[W3C (8fd3955f)] Calling AppiumDriver.setContext() with args: ["CHROMIUM","8fd3955f-3ca9-4678-849f-8fac412a6347"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","CHROMIUM"]
[AndroidDriver] Connecting to chrome-backed webview context 'CHROMIUM'
[AndroidDriver] Found existing Chromedriver for context 'CHROMIUM'. Using it.
[WD Proxy] Matched '/url' to command name 'getUrl'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /url] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/wd/hub/session/aa3ae372d50348a0bbe746116f9e04b3/url] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"16c2134a-84d5-4ca7-98d8-9cf96217376d","status":0,"value":true}
[W3C (2464c639)] Responding to client with driver.performTouch() result: true
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/touch/perform [39m[32m200[39m [90m13457 ms - 14[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/context[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"name":"CHROMIUM"}[39m
[W3C (2464c639)] Calling AppiumDriver.setContext() with args: ["CHROMIUM","2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","CHROMIUM"]
[AndroidDriver] Connecting to chrome-backed webview context 'CHROMIUM'
[AndroidDriver] Found existing Chromedriver for context 'CHROMIUM'. Using it.
[WD Proxy] Matched '/url' to command name 'getUrl'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /url] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd/url] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd\",\"status\":0,\"value\":\"https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=StWmXJXmJtHq-gTwkrqwBg&q=star+wars&oq=star+wars&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.12..0i131j0j46i131j0j0i131j46i131j0j46.10902.22037..27071...0.0..0.1451.6075.2-2j3j1j1j1j2......0....1.......0..46i275.inyUIvu9Es8\"}"
[W3C (2464c639)] Responding to client with driver.setContext() result: null
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/context [39m[32m200[39m [90m13084 ms - 14[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/timeouts[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"implicit":30000}[39m
[W3C (2464c639)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[WD Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/timeouts' to command name 'timeouts'
[Protocol Converter] Will send the following request bodies to /timeouts: [{"type":"implicit","ms":30000}]
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/timeouts] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd/timeouts] with body: {"type":"implicit","ms":30000}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd","status":0,"value":null}
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId 67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd with 2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/timeouts [39m[32m200[39m [90m165 ms - 76[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/elements[39m
[HTTP] [90m{"using":"name","value":"q"}[39m
[W3C (2464c639)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[WD Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/elements' to command name 'findElements'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/elements] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd/elements] with body: {"using":"name","value":"q"}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd","status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"0.5466260018440561-1"}]}
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId 67b7b41cf15632508b04b6bfc48f62cd with 2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596
[HTTP] [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/elements [39m[32m200[39m [90m507 ms - 108[39m
[HTTP] [90m[39m
[HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/2464c639-5ba7-49f5-842a-dadd77f4e596/context[39m
```